# how to trigger an anchor tag resides on the page by clicking on another anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have model where i have two links click and click1 the pop is behind click and i want to trigger the popup when user clicks on click1 how can i do that .
The anchor tags are here.

```
 <a href="#modal">Click</a>
    <a href="#modal1">Click1</a>
```

And the script i have written for it.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#model1").click(function(){
     $("#model").trigger("click");
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: any error in browser console?

Comment: Are the id's in your jquery a typo ?

Comment: nope i dont have any error

Comment: Actually I just noticed that you don't have any id's ? Do you want to query them on the `href` attribute ? Perhaps you can give us the big picture ?

Comment: now i gave them ids too but still the click is not triggerd when i clicks on click1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok its so simple assign an id to second link like that.

```
<a href="#modal">Click</a>
<a href="#" id=modal1>Click1</a>
```

and write the javascript for it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#modal2").on("click", function(e) {
    location.href = "#modal";
    e.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Because as far as I am seeing that the popup is loading after first link href so why we don't redirect this second click to this first link href where the popup resides and I hope it will work.

Comment: yes the popup is belong to href you are quite right let me check it

Answer (score 1):

Change it to the code below, if you like to leave your HTML code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("a[href=#modal1]").click(function(){
    $("a[href=#modal]").trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

Or change your HTML to the code below, if you like to leave your JS code:

```
<a href="#modal" id="modal">Click</a>
<a href="#modal1" id="modal1">Click1</a>
```

The second variation has much better performance.

Comment: If you're adding an Id to the elements, you might as well query them by it, right ? (it will be a lot faster)

Comment: There should be something wrong with your modals, I think. It seems, that nothing happens, when you trigger the click. Can you check that?

Comment: yes i have checked it and you are right nothing is happening

Comment: I think I have given what he is needing.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but I'll give it a shot anyway:

Say you have the following markup:

```
<a href="#" id="modal1">Modal 1</a>
<a href="#" id="modal2">Modal 2</a>
```

Now as far as I understood you want to trigger the click event on the second anchor by clicking the first. Here it is:

```
$("#modal1").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#modal2").click();
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#modal2").on("click", function(e) {
    alert("MODAL 2 CLICKED");
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tg8p8/) trying to demonstrate it.

In case you're looking for a way to redirect to Modal2 by clicking on Modal1 just by invoking the `click` event wont work. If that's the case you need to look for a different approach, perhaps reading the `href` attribute and redirecting the user to the url.

Comment: work fine but not loading my popup which is behind the model2 how cal i load that popup

Comment: What are you using for a "popup" ? Are you using a plugin ? Which one ?